# How to allow kubernetes/calico traffic through iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, kubernetes

I have installed kubespray on my host. I want to close all ports on my host except the required ports. I want to add these rules:

```shell
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22,80,443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

But there's a problem. The last rule blocks kubernetes traffic. Examples of such traffic:

```
Sep 28 01:37:01 node1 kernel: [1034725.304114] Iptables: Drop close ip: IN=calif886a61144a OUT= MAC=ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:ee:52:e2:a2:07:10:34:08:00 SRC=10.233.102.148 DST=169.254.25.10 LEN=45 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=25074 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=44106 DPT=53 LEN=25 MARK=0x40000
Sep 28 01:32:22 node1 kernel: [1034445.773838] Iptables: Drop close ip: IN=vxlan.calico OUT= MAC= SRC=10.233.102.128 DST=239.192.152.143 LEN=165 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=32 ID=60561 PROTO=UDP SPT=58704 DPT=6771 LEN=145
Sep 29 00:00:02 host1 kernel: [10232.158702] Ip6tables: Drop other: IN=enp9s0 OUT= MAC= SRC=2a01:04f9:003b:4714:0000:0000:0000:0002 DST=ff15:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:efc0:988f LEN=187 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=32 FLOWLBL=553201 PROTO=UDP SPT=6771 DPT=6771 LEN=147
```

In iptables there are also rules created by kubernetes. But I took this into account and insert my own rules after them. It turns out that kubernetes traffic reaches the end of the INPUT chain.

What rules can I use to allow all kubernetes traffic? How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way. Consider using [hostendpoint](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/reference/host-endpoints/) policies.

[Here](https://github.com/frozenprocess/Tigera-Presentations/tree/master/2023-03-30.container-and-Kubernetes-security-policy-design/04.best-practices-for-securing-a-Kubernetes-environment) is a tutorial that I've done a similar thing for a k3s cluster.